# ffmpeg add scaled logo with two outputs

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, watermark

I want to add a scaled logo with 2 outputs.

For 1 output this works for me:

```
-filter_complex '[1:v]scale=156:94,overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10'
```

But it does not work for 2 outputs in one ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [split filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split) and [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=156:94[logo];[0][logo]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,split=outputs=2[v1][v2]" -map "[v1]" output1.mp4 -map "[v2]" output2.mkv
```